# ie9 media query device-width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, media-queries, device-width

I am working with media query, for a desktop version of a website.
The behavior that I was looking for was:
-   Full screen rendering
-   No redimensionning when minimizing the viewport (the right sided content is hidden)

So I defined ranges of screen resolutions, and tried with min and max device width like this, on my .css file:

```
@media screen and (max-device width:1535px) and (min-device-width:1365px)  {
    html{
    font-size:80%;
    }
    #mainframe{
    width:1000px;
    }
}
```

This is working well on chrome and firefox but after research device-width seems not to be compliant with ie 9. (min-width workà

( I added this meta tag on my html file :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

with no effect)

Is there a way to bypass this?